# Compute $\sqrt[7]{0.999}$ to three decimal places.(From Gelfand's Algebra text.)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

After a brief introduction to roots(imaginary numbers were not introduced yet), this question is asked. I am apparently expected to find the answer using elementary algebraic manipulation. I have tried playing around with the problem and observed

$\sqrt[7]{0.999} = {(1-\frac{1}{1000}})^\frac{1}{7} = (\frac{(3)^3(37)}{10^3})^\frac{1}{7}$

But do not get how to solve the problem.Any helpful ideas will be appreciated.

PS: Inequalities and binomial series were not yet introduced in the text.I have only a rudimentary knowledge of maths, so keep the answers simple and within the scope of elementary algebra.

I have edited this problem,adding context. Do not penalize previous answers which used calculus. :)

Comment: the question is marked as "precalculus" but the easiest way to justify the "obvious" answer, $1.000$ (to 3dp), is to look at the derivative of $x^7$.

Comment: See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 3):

Rob Arthan wrote in a comment: "What is clear is that Gelfand expected his readers to be prepared to do the long multiplications that show that $0.9995^3<0.999$ (no calculus required!)".

To fill in this gap, I'd like to note that we don't actually have to do the multiplication. Note that $0.9995 = 1 - 0.005$.  Therefore we have

$0.9995^3 = (1-0.005)^3 = 1 - 3 \times 0.005 + 3 \times 0.005^2 - 0.005^3$

by the binomial theorem.  (If one has not seen the binomial theorem, it's not hard to just expand $(1-x)^3$ "by hand" and plug in $x = 0.005$.)  But $3 \times 0.005^2 < 0.005$.  Thus

$1 - 3 \times 0.005 + 3 \times 0.005^2 - 0.005^3 < 1 - 3 \times 0.005 + 0.005 - 0 = 0.999$

which proves the desired result.

Comment: What gap are you filling in? My rather brash thinking was that Gelfand just expected his readers to do the long multiplications (and that they would be pleasantly surprised that two long multiplications get you to the answer,not six). Yes, you can be smart about this, but my conjecture is that at the time Gelfand was writing any reader would be expected to be able solve the problem the direct way (and maybe glean bonus points for a smarter answer like yours).

Comment: I don't agree with your assumption; my assumption is that Gelfand was looking for a smarter answer like mine, given that the numbers involved are so close to 1.  (If he'd asked, say, to compute the cube root of 3.257, then I'd expect that he was looking for the long-multiplication answer.)  But I can't prove this.

Comment: I was stating a conjecture, not an assumption. I really do believe that Gelfand would have expected his readers to be able to do the necessary long multiplications if they couldn't find a smarter way.

Comment: @RobArthan On the contrary, I think Gelfand would have expected his readers to have heard of the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 2):

For a general answer, I would use the Taylor expansion of $(1+x)^a$:

$$(1+x)^a = 1+ax+\frac{a(a-1)}{2}x^2+ \cdots + \frac{a(a-1)\cdots(a+1-n)}{n!}x^n+\cdots$$

Here with $a=1/7$ and $x=-0.001$

Answer (score 0):

The taylor series of $\sqrt[a]{1-x}$
$$ y=1-\frac{x}{a}-.-.-.$$ 
at $x=0.001$ and a=7
$$y=1-0.001/7$$

$$\sqrt[7]{0.999}=1-\frac{1}{7000}=0.9998571$$

Answer (score 0):

For a precalculus solution, you presumably can't use the Taylor series.  You can note that $0.9995^7 \lt 0.997$ (shown here by [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.9995%5E7)), so $\sqrt[7]{0.999} \gt 0.9995$ and to three decimal places it will round to $1.000$